# Swift 2 warning: Passing 2 arguments to a callee as a single tuple value is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift

I have code like this:

```
func newContent(jsonData: [String:AnyObject]) {
    if let userContent: (User, String) = Helper.createUserFromWritingContent(jsonData) {
        newContent?(userContent) // here is the warning: Passing 2 arguments to a callee as a single tuple value is deprecated
    }
}
```

How can I solve this warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning is specified in [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/Misc/misc_diagnostics.swift)

Swift 3 will deprecate option of sending tuple as a argument. Try this one

```
func newAnswerWritingContent(jsonData: [String:AnyObject]) {
   if let userContent: (BRSLegacyUser, String) = CometHelper.createBRSAnwerFromWritingContent(jsonData) {
      let user = userContent.0
      let content = userContent.1
       newAnswerWritingContent?(user,content)
   }
}
```

Comment: Better: `let (user, content) = userContent`

Answer (score 4):

Swift used to let you do this:

```
func sum(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
  return x + y
}
let params = (1,1)
sum(params) // <<== This is deprecated
```

Function `sum` takes two arguments, yet you call it with a single parameter - a tuple carrying both arguments.

This behavior is deprecated in Swift 2 for reasons outlined [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md).

Since the only tuple in your code is `(User, String)`, this should fix the problem:

```
newContent?(userContent.0, userContent.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem because I wanted two different sets of default parameters while keeping my code readable. I solved it by creating a `typealias` for my parameters.

```
typealias exampleParams = (param1: CGFloat, param2: CGFloat)

var exampleDefaultOpen: exampleParams = (param1: 0, param2: 20)
var exampleDefaultClose: exampleParams = (param1: 1, param2: 0)

func example(_ params: exampleParams) {
    // do something with params.param1 and params.param2
}
```

This allows for setting to default:

```
example(exampleDefaultOpen)
```

but also for custom params like this:

```
example((param1: 2, param2: 50))
```